# How to update variable in OnStart() after notificationdatasetchanged() call in customadapter

Tags: java, android

What is want is to update total number in textview in one activity. i have a custom adapter which calls Arraylist in this activity then populates in listview, this adapter also has image view which removes the list item and does notifydatasetchanged().

this is my customadapter

```
private ArrayList<DataModel> dataSet;
Context mContext;

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtName;
    TextView txtType;
    Button remove;
}

public CustomAdapterForData(ArrayList<DataModel> data, Context context) {
    super(context, R.layout.fields, data);
    this.dataSet = data;
    this.mContext=context;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int position = (Integer) view.getTag();
    Object object = getItem(position);
    DataModel dataModel = (DataModel) object;

    switch (view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.btnRemove:
            remove(dataModel);
           // dataSet.remove(position);
            //dataSet.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    DataModel dataModel = getItem(position);
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag

    final View result;

    if (convertView == null) {

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fields, parent, false);
        viewHolder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fieldName);
        viewHolder.txtType = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrize);
        viewHolder.remove = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnRemove);

        result=convertView;

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        result=convertView;
    }

    viewHolder.txtName.setText(dataModel.getFieldName());
    viewHolder.txtType.setText(dataModel.getType());
    viewHolder.remove.setOnClickListener(this);
    viewHolder.remove.setTag(position);

    return convertView;
}
```

after that this is my onstart()

```
protected void onStart() {

   //if ((dataModels.size()!=0)){


    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    adapter = new CustomAdapterForData(dataModels, getApplicationContext());

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    dataModelsnew = dataModels;
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTotal);
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < dataModelsnew.size(); i++){
        sum = sum + dataModelsnew.get(i).getPrize();
    }
    tv.setText("Total : " + String.valueOf(Math.round(sum)*100d/100d));


    //}

    super.onStart();
}
```

what i want is populate latest value in textview which is sum of double (one element of ArrayList).Please help me to resolve this.
Thanks in advance. The variable i want to update after i remove something from list view otherwise it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DataSetObservers to detect any changes in your data:

```
final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTotal);
adapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            super.onChanged();

            double sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0 ; i < dataModels.size(); i++){
                sum = sum + dataModels.get(i).getPrize();
            }
            tv.setText("Total : " + String.valueOf(Math.round(sum)*100d/100d));
    }
});
```